# HTML Symbols not changing colors on Android Apps made by React Native

Tags: android, html, ios, react-native

As shown below in the picture some of the HTML Symbol doesn't change color on the Android version of the app created using React Native even when I change the font color like: `<Text style={{color: 'white'}}>&#x25B6;<Text>`. They change the color as expected on iOS. What could possibly be the reason and how to resolve? **I don't want to use Icons as a workaround.**

[image]